# How to use Lottie Json file with arrow function in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, lottie

**How to use lottie Jason File with arrow function In React-Native**

This code working correctly

```
import React from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class BasicExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    
    return (
 
    <LottieView source={require('./lotties/rocket.json')} autoPlay loop />
 
    )
  }
}
```

But this code not working it giving error. How to use LottieView with arrow function

```
import React from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

const App = () => {
  render(); {
    return(
      <LottieView source={require('./lotties/rocket.json')} autoPlay loop />
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you write functional components

```js
const App = () => {
  render(); {
    return(
      <LottieView source={require('./lotties/rocket.json')} autoPlay loop />
    );
  }
}
```

you don't have to create a render function inside it, try the following

```
const App = () => {
    return(
      <LottieView source={require('./lotties/rocket.json')} autoPlay loop />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to nest it in a view and then give it a height and a width maybe ...

And also, you dont need a render in a functional component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
    
const App = () => {
    
  return(
    <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
      <LottieView source={require('./lotties/rocket.json')} autoPlay loop />
    </View>
   );

}

export default App;
```